# Display the Array in JMeter

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I would like to ask whether it is possible on JMeter to recreate the response on the web browser. Just some quick tip will do. Here is the response that it needs.

[image: Image for the response for JMeter]

My configuration is that I have a CSV file that contains all the ID i need. Then it is inside an Loop controller where I loop it for many times as I needed for selection.

[image: Configuration]

Hope someone can help me. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use [Loop Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Loop_Controller) for this as it will read one entry per Loop Controller's iteration.

If you want to create a request having many JSON objects originating from CSV file I would recommend doing it via [JSR223 PreProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PreProcessor) and [Groovy language](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black/).

The Groovy class you're looking for is [JsonBuilder](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/2.4.7/html/gapi/groovy/json/JsonBuilder.html).

If you need further help consider providing:

1. Screenshot of the [CSV Data Set Config](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config)
2. At least first 2 lines of the CSV file **as text**
3. At least 2 first JSON objects of the request **as text**

Comment: Kindly see your request file. thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

Here are the things that you are asking.

[image: CSV Data Config screenshot]

[image: CSV file]

[image: Selection of Item to the system]

[image: Example of the HTTP Request]